# Visit Pakistan for a week

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, airport-security, pakistan

I'm an American citizen, born and raised in the US. I spent a week in Pakistan, and upon returning today, I was questioned for about 5 minutes. Why is that? I'm 24 years old, and felt really uncomfortable being questioned while entering my own country. I told them I visited Pakistan to visit my relatives.

Comment: Extra questioning is not a big deal, and can be somewhat random. I had a lengthy Q&A returning from a scuba trip to the Cayman Islands, and am not exactly someone with the means to be going down there for tax shelter activities. That said, Pakistan is not currently very popular with the U.S. government for various reasons, and any visit there for any reason is likely to bring at least some extra scrutiny, as might a trip to Cuba or Iran for example.

Answer (score 2):

Osama bin Ladin was [found and killed in Pakistan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Osama_bin_Laden), one of al-Qaeda's alleged senior operatives, [Adam Pearlman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Yahiye_Gadahn), is an American citizen that is supposed to have joined al Qaeda while in Pakistan, the US Department of State recommends US citizens [avoid Pakistan for all but essential travel](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/alertswarnings/pakistan-travel-warning.html) due to terroristic threats, the [2008 Mumbai attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Mumbai_attacks) were carried out by Pakistanis, allegedly with the support of Pakistani's ISI, etc.

To put it bluntly, Pakistan is probably seen by some as a terrorist breeding ground.

Comment: Silly answer, there is nothing as "terrorist breeding ground".

Comment: None-the-less, I think it is fair to state that some see it that way, which is what my answer says. Not that it **is** but that that is how it is **seen**. https://www.google.com/#q=terrorist+breeding+ground brings up 239,000 results so it is hardly a term that I invented.